# How do I use Find and FindNext within another If Then statement?

Tags: vba, if-statement, find

I am trying to:

1. Find a variable called LeftTD based on a string "Foot Strike" (this part of the code works, thanks to help from a previous question!)
2. Find the next LeftTD in the list and call it LeftTDx
3. Read/Message Box the LeftTD and the LeftTDx value
4. Do this again until column H is empty

The input data looks like this:
[Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZyB5.png)

So I want the first message box to tell me, "step starts in row 9 and ends in row 29". The second message box I want to tell me, "step starts in row 29 and ends in row 34".

And the code, which runs as is because it only does steps 1 and 4 (see above) and I have everything else commented out:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LeftStrike As Range, FrameLTD As Range, LeftStrike2 As Range 
Dim lrL As Long

lrL = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'COMMENT: set LeftTD= to something?
Set LeftStrike = ws.Range("H2:H" & lrL) 'COMMENT: .Find(LeftTD)


For Each FrameLTD In LeftStrike
   If InStr(FrameLTD, "Foot Strike") Then
           LeftTD = FrameLTD.Offset(0, 1)
           'COMMENT: LeftTDx = LeftTD.FindNext or is it too easy to ask VBA for : LeftTDx = LeftTD +1
           'COMMENT:StepEnd = LeftTDx.value 
     
    MsgBox "Step starts in row " & LeftTD & " and ends before row " 'COMMENT:& StepEnd
    
    End If
Next FrameLTD
 
End Sub
```

So I guess my question is, how do I set the Find and Find Next code within my already established If Then statement that looks for the string?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is what you want but I think it looks a lot like it. Please give it a try.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Ws          As Worksheet
    Dim TdStart     As Long             ' start of range
    Dim Rl          As Long             ' last row
    Dim R           As Long             ' row counter

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With Ws
        Rl = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        TdStart = 2                          ' start searching in row 2
        For R = (TdStart + 1) To Rl
            ' "Foot Strike" can be anywhere in the cell's text
            '   this test is case sensitive
            If InStr(.Cells(R, "H").Value, "Foot Strike") Or R = Rl Then
                MsgBox "Step starts in row " & TdStart & _
                       " and ends in row " & (R - IIf(R = Rl, 0, 1))
                TdStart = R
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW, unless you want to use `Ws` again later you needn't declare it. Instead you can directly use `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: This code you set does run, but does not do what I want. I do see what you were going for though, so thank you for trying! This finds the string "foot strike" and tells me the row number of the value, then the row of the value before the next "foot strike" . In that list there are "Foot strikes" and "foot offs" . For this program, I would like to ignore the "foot offs" and any other foot events that may be in the list, and just look at the first footstrike value, and then the next foot strike value minus 1.

Comment: I would like to amend my question: I just realized I can always delete the last row later in the code. Now, I just want this code to tell me the first "Foot Strike" value and the next "Foot strike" value. So the first and the second value, and then after that, the second value and the third value, then the third and the fourth, and so on. Is this possible??

Comment: In order to maintain a direct relationship between question and answer, please refrain from "amending the question" in the comments. You can always edit the question itself. I think my code correctly identifies the rows at "Foot Strike" and before the next. I just don't know where to find the "Foot strike value". Read any cell with `Cells([Row], [Column])`. Once you know the row number as `R` you can read `Cell(R, "K").Value`, if that's where the value is, and `Cells(R + 1, "H").Value` or `Cells(R + 2, "H").Value` if you want to know what's in the next two rows.

Comment: Thank you, Variatus! I will try harder next time to get the language correct and not have to have amendments in the future. The "foot strike values" from my previous comment I meant to be the numbers in Column I of the "Excel data". The values I want to have reported from the message box are as follows: 9 & 29, then 29 & 34, then 34 & 40. The ones your code reports are all of the numbers one excel row higher than 9&29. It's my fault, I asked the original question poorly. Can you still help me?

Comment: If the code returns all the correct numbers but offset by 1 then the simple answer should be to just amend the answer: `MsgBox "Step starts in row " & TdStart - 1 & _
                       " and ends in row " & (R - 1 - IIf(R = Rl, 0, 1))`. I fear this solution may give the wrong answer in the beginnig and/or end of the sheet but a more sophisticated solution would need a picture of your worksheet and if you post it here this thread will not be recognizable anymore. Better ask another question with a picture, with the now current code, and with the now current requirement.